# powershell for diskpart utility in windows

Tags: diskpart, powershell-2.0

I want to avoid using command prompt for diskpart utility but want to know if there is any alternate available in powershell for diskpart to handle windows Dynamic disks ?

Answer (score 0):

Powershell uses cmdlets. Depending on your requirements, You will have to use one or a combination of the following cmdlets:

- [Get-Partition](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/get-partition?view=windowsserver2019-ps) : Returns a list of all partition objects visible on all disks, or optionally a filtered list using specified parameters.
- [Get-Disk](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/get-disk?view=windowsserver2019-ps): Gets one or more disks visible to the operating system.
- [Set-Disk](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/set-disk?view=windowsserver2019-ps): Takes a Disk object or unique disk identifiers and a set of attributes, and updates the physical disk on the system.
- [Set-Partition](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/set-partition?view=windowsserver2019-ps): Sets attributes of a partition, such as active, read-only, and offline states.
- [Clear-Disk](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/clear-disk?view=windowsserver2019-ps): Cleans a disk by removing all partition information and un-initializing it, erasing all data on the disk.
- [New-Partition](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/new-partition?view=windowsserver2019-ps): Creates a new partition on an existing Disk object.
- [Get-Volume](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/get-volume?view=windowsserver2019-ps): Gets the specified Volume object, or all Volume objects if no filter is provided.
- [Format-Volume](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/format-volume?view=windowsserver2019-ps): Formats one or more existing volumes or a new volume on an existing partition.
- [New-Volume](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/new-volume?view=windowsserver2019-ps): Creates a volume with the specified file system.

You should probably update your version of Powershell as you mentioned version 2 on the tags.